# E/AndroidRuntime(1899): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Tags: android

I try to do a simple programm where I load an app with tabs. But I have some errors that i don't understand. It would be great if you could help me.

Thank you in advance.

Errors :

```
02-01 14:03:57.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1899): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.customtabs/com.example.customtabs.CustomtabsActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'
02-01 14:03:57.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
02-01 14:03:57.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
02-01 14:03:57.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
02-01 14:03:57.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
02-01 14:03:57.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-01 14:03:57.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-01 14:03:57.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
02-01 14:03:57.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-01 14:03:57.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-01 14:03:57.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
02-01 14:03:57.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
02-01 14:03:57.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1899): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'
02-01 14:03:57.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.app.TabActivity.onContentChanged(TabActivity.java:131)
02-01 14:03:57.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:381)
02-01 14:03:57.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
02-01 14:03:57.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at com.example.customtabs.CustomtabsActivity.onCreate(CustomtabsActivity.java:14)
02-01 14:03:57.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
02-01 14:03:57.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
02-01 14:03:57.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
02-01 14:03:57.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     ... 10 more
```

Main file 
    CustomtabsActivity.java :

```
package com.example.customtabs;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class CustomtabsActivity extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customtabs);

        Resources res = getResources(); 
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 
        TabHost.TabSpec spec; 
        Intent intent; 

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab1.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Widget").setIndicator("DateTime", res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_today)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab2.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Form").setIndicator("Form", res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_manage)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab3.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("onglet3").setIndicator("onglet3", res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_mapmode)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }

}
```

Tab1.java :

```
package com.example.customtabs;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;



public class Tab1 extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.onglet1);
    }
}a
```

Tab2.java and Tab3.java are almost the same than Tab1.java.

Comment: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'

Comment: Whenever you get an errors like this, pay attention to the "caused by" line: `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'`. It's telling you what to do!

Comment: You have wrong layout (activity_customtabs.xml). See example http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/android-tabwidget-example.html

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'
```

Just make sure your layout has this:

```
<TabHost android:id="*@android:id/tabhost"
```